# TAR file format issue

Tags: compression, zip, gzip, tar, bzip2

It is unclear to me, what is a correct `.tar` file format, as I am experiencing proper functionality with three scenarios *(see below)*.

Based on `.tar` specification I have been working with, the `magic` field (ustar) is null-terminated character string and `version` field is octal number with no trailing nulls.

However I've review several `.tar` files I found on my server and I found different implementation of `magic` and `version` field and all three of them seems to work properly, probably because system ignore those fields.

See different (3) bytes between words **ustar** and **root** in the following examples >>

Scenario 1 (`20 20 00`):

```
 000000F0      00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00      ............
 000000FC      00 00 00 00 | 00 75 73 74 | 61 72 20 20      .....ustar  
 00000108      00 72 6F 6F | 74 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00      .root.......
 00000114      00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00      ............
```

Scenario 2 (`00 20 20`):

```
 000000F0      00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00      ............
 000000FC      00 00 00 00 | 00 75 73 74 | 61 72 00 20      .....ustar. 
 00000108      20 72 6F 6F | 74 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00      root.......
 00000114      00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00      ............
```

Scenario 3 (`00 00 00`):

```
 000000F0      00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00      ............
 000000FC      00 00 00 00 | 00 75 73 74 | 61 72 00 00      .....ustar..
 00000108      00 72 6F 6F | 74 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00      .root.......
 00000114      00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00      ............
```

Which one is the correct format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion none of your examples is the correct one, at least not for the POSIX format.
As you can read [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html):

```
/* tar Header Block, from POSIX 1003.1-1990. */
/* POSIX header */

struct posix_header {   /* byte offset */
  char name[100];               /*   0 */
  char mode[8];                 /* 100 */
  char uid[8];                  /* 108 */
  char gid[8];                  /* 116 */
  char size[12];                /* 124 */
  char mtime[12];               /* 136 */
  char chksum[8];               /* 148 */
  char typeflag;                /* 156 */
  char linkname[100];           /* 157 */
  char magic[6];                /* 257 */
  char version[2];              /* 263 */
  char uname[32];               /* 265 */
  char gname[32];               /* 297 */
  char devmajor[8];             /* 329 */
  char devminor[8];             /* 337 */
  char prefix[155];             /* 345 */
};

#define TMAGIC   "ustar"        /* ustar and a null */
#define TMAGLEN  6
#define TVERSION "00"           /* 00 and no null */
#define TVERSLEN 2
```

The format of your first example (`Scenario 1`) seems to be matching with the old GNU header format:

```
/* OLDGNU_MAGIC uses both magic and version fields, which are contiguous.
   Found in an archive, it indicates an old GNU header format, which will be
   hopefully become obsolescent.  With OLDGNU_MAGIC, uname and gname are
   valid, though the header is not truly POSIX conforming */

#define OLDGNU_MAGIC "ustar  "  /* 7 chars and a null */
```

In both your second and third examples (`Scenario 2` and `Scenario 3`), the `version` field is set to an unexpected value (according to the above documentation, the correct value should be `00` ASCII or `0x30 0x30` hex), so this field is most likely ignored.

Comment: Try to make some `.tar` file on your end and then check that file with hex viewer, is you will see `ustar00` in its header. I was expecting that as well, but I didn't find it in any of several files I checked, so..?!

Comment: I've made a couple of tests on a Centos 5.9 system, and I've discovered that by default the output file contains "ustar  ", since the TAR command is a GNU version. If I specify the `--posix` option, the output file contains "ustar00" as expected.

Comment: A further reference: [format of tape archive files](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=5&topic=tar)

Answer (score 1):

With Fedora 18 if I execute this command:

```
tar --format=posix -cvf testPOSIX.tar test.txt
```

I have a POSIX tar file format with: ustar\0 (0x757374617200)

else if I execute this:

```
tar --format=gnu -cvf testGNU.tar test.txt
```

I have a GNU tar file format with: ustar 0x20 0x20 0x00 (0x7573746172202000) (old gnu format)

From /usr/share/magic file:

```
# POSIX tar archives
257 string      ustar\0     POSIX tar archive
!:mime  application/x-tar # encoding: posix
257 string      ustar\040\040\0 GNU tar archive
!:mime  application/x-tar # encoding: gnu
```

0x20 is 40 in octal.

I've also tried to edit the hex code with:

```
00 20 20
```

and however the tar worked correctly. I've exctract test.txt without problem.

but when I've tried to edit the hex code with:

```
00 00 00
```

The tar was not recognized.

So, my conclusion is that the correct format is:

```
20 20 00
```

Comment: CentOS 6 has no problem with `00 00 00`

Comment: The correct magic according to POSIX is "ustar\0" and then "00" where `"ustar\0"` is the magic and `"00"` is the version.